# Get a number present after a particular pattern of a matching string which consists of word and number

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

This is the input string:

```
text Expedien N0 18-00232995
$cat input_file
some text before Expedien: 1-21-212-16-26 some random text
Reference RE9833 of all sentences.
abc
123
456
something blah blah Ref.: 
tramite  1234567
Ref.:
some junk Expedien N° 18-00777 # some new content
some text Expedien N°18-0022995 # some garbled content
```

For other strings:
This code works but I want to also fetch if, a word consists of a number and I want to find the number after that matching(word-number present as an entity in the list) and so in such a case:

getting output ('Expedien', 'N0') but expected output is ('Expedien N0', '18-00232995').

The code that fetches other entities is as follows:

```
import re
s="""your_text_here"""
my_list = ['Ref.:', 'Reference', 'tramite', 'Expediente', 'Expediente No', 'Expedien N°', 'Exp.No', 'Expedien', 'Expedien N0']
rx = r'(?<!\w)({})\W*([A-Z]*\d+(?:-+[A-Z]*\d+)*)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape,my_list)))
print(re.findall(rx, s))
```

Output:

```
[('Expedien', '1-21-212-16-26'), ('Reference', 'RE9833'), ('tramite', '1234567'), ('Expedien N°', '18-00777'), ('Expedien N°', '18-0022995')]
```

How do I get ('Expedien N0', '18-00232995') this output by manipulating the above regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change is needed for you to get your desired output. In your,

```
my_list = ['Ref.:', 'Reference', 'tramite', 'Expediente', 'Expediente No', 'Expedien N°', 'Exp.No', 'Expedien', 'Expedien N0']
```

You have specified `Expedien` before `Expedien N0` due to which in `text Expedien N0 18-00232995` text `Expedien` matches and `N0` matches in second group and leaves no scope for matching `Expedien N0` as it comes later. Hence if you just change the order in your list and place `Expedien N0` before `Expedien`, then `Expedien N0` matches the first group and `18-00232995` gets captured in second group and gives you your desired results. Check your modified python code below,

```
import re
s="""text Expedien N0 18-00232995
$cat input_file
some text before Expedien: 1-21-212-16-26 some random text
Reference RE9833 of all sentences.
abc
123
456
something blah blah Ref.: 
tramite  1234567
Ref.:
some junk Expedien N° 18-00777 # some new content
some text Expedien N°18-0022995 # some garbled content"""
my_list = ['Ref.:', 'Reference', 'tramite', 'Expediente', 'Expediente No', 'Expedien N°', 'Exp.No', 'Expedien N0', 'Expedien']

rx = r'(?<!\w)({})\W*([A-Z]*\d+(?:-+[A-Z]*\d+)*)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape,my_list)))
print(rx)
print(re.findall(rx, s))
```

Prints,

```
[('Expedien N0', '18-00232995'), ('Expedien', '1-21-212-16-26'), ('Reference', 'RE9833'), ('tramite', '1234567'), ('Expedien N°', '18-00777'), ('Expedien N°', '18-0022995')]
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ You have your intended tuple here in your findall results
```